# Drawing honey comb structure by matlab

Tags: matlab

Graphene Honey comb lattice structure. I am trying to generate graphene honey comb structure. I want to join the nearest neighbors point in the lattice.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my code.

```
X1=0.5:3:10

X2=1.5:3:10

X3=0:3:10;

X4=2:3:10;

for y=0:sqrt(3):10;

a=plot(y,X1,'*--')

hold on

b=plot(y,X2,'*--')

hold on

end

for y=0.5*sqrt(3):sqrt(3):10;

c=plot(y,X3,'*--')

hold on

d=plot(y,X4,'*--')

end
```

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27963305/2586922) helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you might need below code.

```
clear all
close all

X1=0.5:3:9

X2=1.5:3:7.5

X3=0:3:9;

X4=2:3:8;

for m=0:5;

    gap=sqrt(3);
    step=[m m]*sqrt(3);

    for n=1:length(X1)-1
        figure(1)
        line([0 0]*gap+step,[X1(n) X2(n)]);
        line([0.5 0.5]*gap+step,[X3(n+1) X4(n)]);
        line([0 0.5]*gap+step,[X2(n) X4(n)]);
        line([0 0.5]*gap+step,[X1(n+1) X3(n+1)]);
        line([0.5 1]*gap+step,[X3(n+1) X1(n+1)]);
        line([0.5 1]*gap+step,[X4(n) X2(n)]);
        axis([0 11 0 7])
    end

end
```

first of all, I made one row of honey comb, by matlab line function, as below.

[image]

And then, I copied the pattern, 5 times, by for-loop.

[image]

Comment: Adding `axis equal` should fix the aspect ratio.